# Spark SQL how to query columns with nested Json

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have a column `features` in a table with the follwing structure

```
 |-- features: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tectonFeatures: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- featureName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

How do I write a SQL query that gets me any row where `featureName = 'a'` and `results is not empty` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this schema:

```
root
 |-- features: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- tectonFeatures: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- featureName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

and these rows:

```
+--------------------+
|features            |
+--------------------+
|{[{a, [Something]}]}|
|{[{b, []}]}         |
+--------------------+
```

this SQL statement keeps any row that contains at least one pair of `featureName = a` and `size(results) > 0`:

```
select * from test where size(filter(features.tectonFeatures, x -> x.featureName = 'a' and size(x.results) > 0)) > 0
```

Final result:

```
+--------------------+
|features            |
+--------------------+
|{[{a, [Something]}]}|
+--------------------+
```

Good luck!